Why a host with interfaces for networks A and B reply pings to interface A coming from a host at B?
I have a Linux host X with two network interfaces:

eth0 is at 10.0.1.0/24 with IP address 10.0.1.1
eth1 is at 10.0.2.0/24 with IP address 10.0.2.1

I have another Linux host Y at 10.0.1.0/24 network, with IP 10.0.1.2.
I have yet another Linux host Z at 10.0.2.0/24 network, with IP 10.0.2.2.
All of them are Alpine Linux running on VirtualBox.
Host X starts with IP forwarding enabled with net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 at /etc/sysctl.conf.
If Z (10.0.2.2) tries to ping Y(10.0.1.2), it gets a reply as expected.
If Z (10.0.2.2) tries to ping host X at IP 10.0.1.1, it also gets a reply as expected.
When I disable ip forwarding on X with:
# echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
Z(10.0.2.2) does not get a ping reply from Y (10.0.1.2) anymore, but it still does from X at 10.0.1.1. I expected that it would get no reply, since its an address from a different network, and IP forwarding is disabled.
Is this the expected behavior? A config parameter in the Linux kernel? I couldn't find any mention about it on RFC 792, neither in the kernel documentation.
P.S: something that seems particularly odd is that tcpdump on X 10.0.1.1 has no output when an echo request is addressed to it from Z (10.0.2.2) regardless of IP forwarding enabled or not. And yet, if IP forwarding is enabled, it will show the echo requests from Z (10.0.2.2) directed to Y (10.0.1.1) and its respective reply.


Is this the expected behavior?

By default, yes. Linux implements the "weak host model" - this means that packets arriving for the local system are accepted, regardless of the interface they arrive on.
This is in contrast to the "strong host model", which requires that packets arriving are destined for a configured address on the incoming interface.
The strong host model can be emulated using iptables / nftables, by matching packets to the interface and associated address before being accepted.

something that seems particularly odd is that tcpdump on X 10.0.1.1 has no output when an echo request is addressed to it from Z (10.0.2.2)

There is no traffic associated with those pings on the 10.0.1.0/24 subnet or interface, this is all handled within the kernel... again, it's a bit puzzling on the surface, but makes sense in light of the weak host model described above.
Try reconfiguring Z, and removing X as the default route for 10.0.1.0/24, and this behaviour will stop - with or without forwarding enabled.

Interface ip_forward and forwarding settings only care about sending packets out. Since your ping doesn't need to leave the host to generate a reply, it succeeds.
The default for linux is to have all interfaces reply to ARP requests for any IPs on the same host, so you can get some traffic/replies for other interfaces even if you have no routes. This is defined by /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/interface/arp_filter=0.
For some more detail, see: https://sysctl-explorer.net/net/ipv4/arp_filter/
